# Which bibliography style is similar to elsarticle-harv but without parentheses in main text and DOI in the reference list

Tags: bibtex, elsarticle, bibliographystyle

I am looking for a bibliography style similar to elsarticle-harv but without parentheses in main text and DOI in the reference list. For example: I am getting (Andersson (2013)) but I want it to appear in text as (Andersson et al., 2013) and in the list as the following. I am submitting to an Elsevier journal and this example is from one of the recent articles in that journal. I am using bibtex and copying from Google Scholar. Mine always show parenthesis around the year in the main text. Also, mine does not show the DOI.

[image: Borrelia afzelii article]

```
@article{doi:10.1086/669905,
author = {Andersson, Martin and Scherman, Kristin and Råberg, Lars},
title = {Multiple-Strain Infections of Borrelia afzelii: A Role for Within-Host Interactions in the Maintenance of Antigenic Diversity?},
journal = {The American Naturalist},
volume = {181},
number = {4},
pages = {545-554},
year = {2013},
doi = {10.1086/669905},
note ={PMID: 23535618},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.1086/669905},
eprint = {https://doi.org/10.1086/669905},
}
```

uchicago_an181_545.bib